# In MySql convert resulted row from query to comma-separated string

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to covert the result row from the select query into a comma-separated string. I have table in which there are 153 columns. the select query is like as follow

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where id = 3
```

I want all the resulting 153 columns of a row in a comma-separated string. Is there any trick in MySql?

Comment: Does this help? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` function to do that.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(col1, col2,..coln) FROM my_table;
```

EDIT:

get all column names with following query and the substitute that in `CONCAT_WS` function::

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';

SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', col1, col2, ..., coln) 
FROM my_table;
```

or try:

```
SET @query1 = CONCAT('
        SELECT CONCAT_WS(",", ',(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)
                                 FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
                                 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'),')
        FROM    tablew_name'
        );
PREPARE stmt FROM @query1; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: `Group_concat()` will give the results from multiple rows, not multiple comumns.

Comment: @Fluffeh - Yes exactly, I want columns of a single row comma separated (using where clause)

Comment: @hemu Nevermind, I misread the question. Thought you wanted all the columns per row in one field.

Comment: k...your solution seems to be working. I am trying this one - `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) INTO @cols FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'myTable';
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', @cols) FROM myTable WHERE id = 3;` but this is giving me comma seperated name of columns. not values...Any help ?

Comment: ya you need to copy past all those columns to CONCAT_WS function to make new query and don't forget to accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `concat()` function, but you will need to name each column as far as I know.

```
select concat(col1, ',', col2, ',', col3) from myTable where id=3
```

The only way that I know of to get all the columns of a table is `SHOW COLUMNS FROM table` and I guess you could include the results from this into your query but it isn't something that I have ever done before.

Comment: Yes that will work, but I am gonna write down this in trigger. So let's say after 2 months a new column will be added , I will need to edit the trigger code. That's why using column name is not recommended.

Comment: @hemu No worries, from the question, I wasn't sure about the level of knowledge you have. I answered the question as I saw it mate :)